# MySQL query match with alias WHERE not working

Tags: mysql, match, where-clause

why does my sintax is not right?

```
SELECT *,
           MATCH(tags,title,description) AGAINST ('asd jhbdckdsb' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS score 
      FROM blogs WHERE score > 0
  ORDER BY score DESC, insert_datetime DESC, id DESC ;
```

the problem seems to be on WHERE condition :/

Comment: What error message do you get?

Comment: When doing comparison, I always enclose my values in 's ... ie '0', any time I don't, I get errors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

invisible columns and column alias are not allowed in `WHERE` so use `HAVING`

`HAVING score > 0` instead of `WHERE`

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use a column alias in the WHERE clause. You must repeat the MATCH a second time.